# CRM 2013 - Getting input from non crm users

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have a CRM 2013 solution.

It holds information about supervision/auditing sessions with various third parties.

The third parties are not CRM users but it would be valuable to have them pre-answer a line of questions and get that data into the system before the actual session.

Does CRM offer any features that could help us here without creating CRM user accounts for the third parties?

Are there for instance features of creating a CRM web portal questionare with a unique obscure url?

Or are there other CRM 2013 features for external input?

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not a programming related question. Have a look at the solution from ADXStudios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have created a Separate Website and hosted our Custom Aspx Pages there. There we can get input from anyone who is not a CRM User and various third parties.

Also i have created a `Rest Webservice` that take input data from third parties as `JSON` format and creates it in CRM thorugh `Organization WebService.`

//Create Connection with CRM Server

[Connection to CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115190/connection-to-crm)

Then send the required data to the crm through `CRM WebService`.
I think the below link will help
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx