# Connecting to CRM Online from C# using username and password when using Office 365/ADFS SingleSignOn

Tags: c#, authentication, dynamics-crm, office365

We have CRM Online/Office 365 environment synced with an On-premise AD to enable single sign on from the desktop.
However, since enabling this we are unable to connect to CRM Online from C# using a username and password - using the domain username and password results in "clientCredentials.UserName.UserName or clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName MUST be populated!"

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Please show the relevant code you are using to authenticate and connect.

Comment: Same issue. No solution found

Answer (score 0):

Documenting my findings for anyone else that experiences this problem.

I had the same error, and it was caused by the connection string to the CRM online instance having a user name, a password and domain.

When I removed the domain from my connection string, and added to the user name, the problem went away.

This question has some good answers on the correct connection strings to use: [Connection to CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115190/connection-to-crm)

Comment: I am using this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx and I get the same.
How can I print connection string ?

Comment: What did you use for the AuthType ?  and how did you specific the domain  (DOMAIN\me  or me@domain.com) ?

Comment: @EricLabashosky It's been a while, but I think I used the user@domain format - that is what Azure AD wants. Also it is email address@domain in Azure AD, not network login name