# I am not able to connect MS CRM server

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When I try to connect to my MS CRM server using the C# code below.

[image]

I am getting the following error.
[image]

Comment: inlined linked images, improved grammar

Comment: Are you trying to remotely debug CRM? That's what the error suggests you are doing.

Comment: use the simplified connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection to CRM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115190/connection-to-crm)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115190/connection-to-crm

Comment: Try not to step in to object when you're creating `OrganizationServiceProxy` and provide us error message you're getting after it is executed (if it would be any error message there).